# Как можно сравнить двухмерный массив что бы первая часть равнялась одной переменной а другая часть второй переменной

Tags: c#

Как можно сравнить Двухмерный массив что бы первая часть равнялась одной переменной а другая часть второй переменной и вывести что-нибудь в консоль если равняется?
Например массив ar первая часть 1 2 3 вторая часть 3 2 4
Только нужно сравнивать по частям то есть из первый части первый символ потом из первой части второй символ и их второй части второй символ и тд.
Вот код

```
int[,] nums2 = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 } };
int q = 1;
int w = 4;
for(int i =0; i< nums2.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < nums2.GetLength(0); j++)
    {
        if (nums2[i, j] == q && nums2[i, j] == w)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

получить нужно в данном коде 1

Comment: Что именно не получается? Покажите неработающий код. Приведите конкретный пример данных. Если возникает ошибка, то ее текст. Вопросы для людей с хорошим воображением здесь не являются нормальными.

Comment: @aepot Правил Вопрос, получить нужно в данном коде 1.

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Да, Спасибо, удалось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задание, то решение будет такое

```cs
int[,] nums2 = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 } };
int q = 1;
int w = 4;
for (int j = 0; j < nums2.GetLength(1); j++)
{
    if (nums2[0, j] == q && nums2[1, j] == w)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: `...GetLength(1)`, `if (nums2[0, i] == q && nums2[1, i] == w)`

Comment: @Igor точно. спасибо, не часто вижу объявление матрицы литералами в коде, потерял сноровку :)